# Basic issue with PHP preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following array in PHP:

```
$item_array = array("facebook/1377445751.jpg_t","twitter/1377446022.gif_s","flickr/1377531219.png_w","flickr/1377531219.jpg_t_w");
```

I am iterating through this array, removing values that don't match the following regex:

```
(facebook|twitter|flickr)\/(\d{10})\.(jpg|png|gif)_(t_w|t|s|w)
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach($item_array as $key => $item) { 
    if(!preg_match('/(facebook|twitter|flickr)\/(\d{10})\.(jpg|png|gif)_(t_w|t|s|w)/', $item)) {
        unset($item_array[$key]);
    }
}
```

However, when I then use `var_dump()` on `$item_array`, I obtain an empty array. Since the `preg_match` doesn't match any of the array values, I'm under the impression that the problem lies there, even though I've tested it multiple times with RegExr.

Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: You didn't define "working."

Comment: Use a tool like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to figure out what is wrong

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain my predicament. Sorry about that.

Comment: By the way, `$foo = [1,2,3]` is usually considered a better syntax for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see here (click)](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28facebook%7Ctwitter%7Cflickr%29%5C/%28%5Cd%7B10%7D%29%5C.%28jpg%7Cpng%7Cgif%29_%28t_w%7Ct%7Cs%7Cw%29&input=facebook/1377445751.jpg_t%0Atwitter/1377446022.gif_s%0Aflickr/1377531219.png_w%0Aflickr/1377531219.jpg_t_w), your regex works fine. Perhaps you are having an issue you have not stated that deals with using the result.

I suspect that you might be looking for the $matches parameter, which will store your results.

Use like so:

```
preg_match('/(facebook|twitter|flickr)\/(\d{10})\.(jpg|png|gif)_(t_w|t|s|w)/', $item, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This is all working perfectly as you described. I cleaned it up a little bit, but the code is the same. You must have a different problem.

```
$item_array = [
  "facebook/1377445751.jpg_t",
  "twitter/1377446022.gif_s",
  "flickr/1377531219.png_w",
  "flickr/1377531219.jpg_t_w",
  "other stuff that won't match!"
];
foreach($item_array as $key => $item) {
  $foo = preg_match('/(facebook|twitter|flickr)\/(\d{10})\.(jpg|png|gif)_(t_w|t|s|w)/', $item);
  if(!$foo) {
    echo $item; //displays "other stuff that won't match"
    unset($item_array[$key]);
  }
}
var_dump($item_array); //non match is removed
```

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect what my predicament is. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump()` on your `preg_match` to see what is being returned? If you're running a conditional like that, knowing what the condition is would be quite helpful. :)

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. See my update. I recommend structuring your code more like that for clarity.